McGee and the school bully
I am searching for, but not finding, the NCIS episode where Agent McGee is talking to a suspect about how cool school bullying is. "You have long forgotten him, but he will remember your name until his death" or something like this. Just to reveal that he was the one bullied, not the bully: "His name was ..., I will never forget him."
I already asked Google, but it only came up with this remark about its existence, without season or episode:

He rarely gets to interrogate suspects but, when left alone with a school bully, McGee exacts revenge for all the bullying he himself suffered at school. The sincerity of McGee is sufficient to persuade the bully to tell what he knows.

http://www.ncisfanwiki.com/page/Timothy+McGee

Sounds like the episode Deception (Season 3, episode 13) where McGee interrogates a school bully named Jason played by Jesse Plemons. From the script:

MCGEE: Tim and Dan, they must be pretty scared of you, huh?
JASON: What makes you say that?
MCGEE: Come on. They're obviously geeks. We used to shove them into lockers. Pull their gym shorts off in class. Drop their books down the toilet. It was even better if they start crying, right?
JASON: Or wet their pants.
MCGEE: Yeah, well that, too. You know what the best part is? When you get older, you're not going to remember their names, but you know what? They're always going to remember yours. That's pretty cool, huh?
JASON: You know, I really haven't thought about it too much.
MCGEE: Well, I have. You know why? Because I was one of those kids. And I've been looking forward to this day my entire life, dirtbag.


It is Season 3, Episode 13 - Deception. 
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0657990/
